# VBA Excel - Copying Dates from one row to another changes date format

Tags: vba, excel

I need to copy the dates in one column to another. I thought i had done it properly\ however some of the dates change format to USA date format, whilst others remain in the UK format as required for my purpose. Here's what this looks like and the code i use to copy the date, the columns for these dates ar 9 and 11 respectfully.

[image: DatesSample]

```
Sub CopyPlannedDatesToHiddenColumn()

Dim wsCRC As Worksheet
Set wsCRC = Worksheets("CRC")
Dim lrowcrc As Long
lrowcrc = CRC.LastRowInCRC

Dim PlannedDateToCopy As String
Dim i As Integer

For i = 9 To lrowcrc

    PlannedDateToCopy = wsCRC.Cells(i, 9).Value
    wsCRC.Cells(i, 11) = PlannedDateToCopy

Next i

End Sub
```

Any idea why this is happening and how i could get poast this?

Comment: `PlannedDateToCopy` is declared as `string`, so you convert a date value into a string and write a string back into the other cell. Instead try: `wsCRC.Cells(i, 11).Value = wsCRC.Cells(i, 9).Value` so the value is copied and not converted into a string. Also you should [always use `Long` instead of `Integer`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26409520/3219613) especially when handling with row counts. Excel has more rows than `Integer` can handle.

Comment: grabbing `.Value2` and make the variable a `Long`.

Comment: Change the type of PlannedDateToCopy to Date instead of string.

Comment: @Peh Thank you, this has worked!

Comment: @Peh You should post your comment as an answer, the answer.

Comment: @user1016274 Of course, you are right. Done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### What is happening?

The issue is that you declared `PlannedDateToCopy` as type `String`.

The following line

```
PlannedDateToCopy = wsCRC.Cells(i, 9).Value
```

reads the value of the cell as type `Date` and casts it automatically into a `String` for the variable.
You then write that `String` into a new cell …

```
wsCRC.Cells(i, 11) = PlannedDateToCopy
```

and this is why the new cell contains a `String` instead of a `Date`.

---

#### Solution 1: Remove the Variable

The shortest solution would be to write the value directly into the new cell without using a variable:

```
wsCRC.Cells(i, 11).Value = wsCRC.Cells(i, 9).Value
```

---

#### Solution 2: Declare it the Correct Type

If you explicitly need that variable then declare it …

- … as `Date` and then use `.Value`

  ```
  Dim PlannedDateToCopy As Date
  PlannedDateToCopy = wsCRC.Cells(i, 9).Value
  ```
- … or as `Long` and use `.Value2` (see [Range.Value2 Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-value2-property-excel) for explaining the difference)

  ```
  Dim PlannedDateToCopy As Long
  PlannedDateToCopy = wsCRC.Cells(i, 9).Value2
  ```

*Like* @Vinicius *and* @Scott Craner *suggested in their comments.*

---

#### Additional Note

You should [always use `Long` instead of `Integer`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26409520/3219613) unless you need to communicate with old APIs. Especially when handling with row counts. Excel has more rows (in newer versions) than `Integer` can handle:

```
Dim i As Long
```